# Blazor Sub menus with <NavLink>

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm using the Blazor template which using the NavLink component.  This wraps up the bootstrap menu so it's basically bootstrap underneath.

I cannot find any documentation about NavLink.  I've seen a couple articles that explain some of the features such as Matching.

What is not explained is how to create sub menus.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: can u plz share the code in codepen or fiddle?

Comment: This probably may help you how to create menus and sub-menus: https://github.com/Blazored/Menu

Answer (score 3):

The `NavLink` components is just a `<a>` tag but with services to update its css class.
[NavLink code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavLink.cs)

If you want create a sub menu with bootstrap 4, read the bootstrap 4 doc on [Navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/) and [NavBar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/). (Blazor samples and templates use a [NavBar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/))

Comment: Open source matters.